# MiKTex won't compile the file

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I have a huge problem.

I have a tex file I'm trying to compile with

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "%name"
```

But it will get stuck. I'm sorry I can't provide the full example - it's quite complicated and I don't understand at all why it happens so I can't simplify it.

I'm providing [the log file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7A-wdZw6xSZaC1VenVlQ0V5eVU). I think there's nothing wrong with the document itself. My template collects other .tex files and puts them into a big file. It works in most cases, but if I include more files (I'm including 6 in this example), something like this will happen (the ending of the log file is always the same).

Hopefully someone will be able to understand it from log file. I have already tried to reboot / reinstall / restore / update MiKTeX. It didn't help.

Comment: the log file that you show only appears to be the start of the file, it shows no error, but stops at page 2.

Comment: you can always provide a full example.  take a copy of your original and just delete everything after the error and everything before the error that you can delete  while still showing the problem. Once the document is small enough to post you can add it to the question.

Comment: Your problem is most probably with your document. Reinstalling miktex will no help. You must analyze your document and find the clue there.